# Remapping return key to <C-p>

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, autocompletion

Because I am used to autocompleting by pressing the return/enter key, I want to remap the return key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> in insert mode. **However**, I only want to remap it when the cursor is directly behind a letter (a-z).

Is this possible?

Comment: With an expr mapping/custom function, maybe, but what is it you want to accomplish in both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it is!

Try this expression mapping:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> getline('.')[col('.') - 2] =~ '\a' ? "\<C-P>" : "\<CR>"
```

How this works:

- `getline('.')[col('.') - 2]`: This returns the character immediately before the cursor (i.e. the one you just typed).
- `=~ '\a'`: This checks if the character is an alphabetic character a-z or A-Z
- `? "\<C-P>" : "\<CR>"`: If the character is alphabetic then your keypress is mapped to `<C-P>`. If not, it is mapped to `<CR>`.

For more details, see:

- `:help :map-expr`
- `:help expr1`
- `:help getline()`
- `:help col()`
- `:help \a`